# Asynchronous NSURLConnection Scheme Tutorial

Tags: nsurlconnection

I am looking for a good tutorial on using the NSURLConnection Asynchronous request. I have been looking around in stackoverflow and Google but could not find one. This can be a duplicate of zillions of questions like this here. But please direct me to the correct tutorial, I have used ASIHTTPRequest before, but I have not used the Apple provided library before.

Comment: Are there specific parts you don't understand? At core, its only a couple of methods...

Comment: Yes I am trying to understand this method sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: So How should I notify that the request has been processed. What exactly does this completionHandler do? This is the right method to process async requests right? Or are there any other methods

Comment: Yes, that way or the delegate methods, either is good. Are you familiar with blocks?

Comment: Can you explain me the delegate methods are good?If i do not want to use sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: which method should I use? I am not familiar with blocks

Comment: Updated my answer, delegates if you want them won't be quick, I have hated using them for NSURLConnection since the day blocks were introduced in objective-c.

Comment: @jrturton Is there a way of implementing timeouts and cancelling requests when I use this method sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would provide you with one written myself, however I would HIGHLY recommend using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), it's a wrapper above the NSURLConnection / NSURLRequest system that has a much cleaner flow, you can also use basic NSURLRequests / Connections with this, along with regular NSOperationQueues. The library also uses cocoa pods, and to be honest you really can't get much cleaner then that.

```
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[mainQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.63:7070/api/Misc/GetFuelTypes"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:@{@"Accepts-Encoding": @"gzip", @"Accept": @"application/json"}];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:mainQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Status Code: %li %@", (long)urlResponse.statusCode, [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:urlResponse.statusCode]);
        NSLog(@"Response Body: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"An error occured, Status Code: %i", urlResponse.statusCode);
        NSLog(@"Description: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"Response Body: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
}];
```

The mainQueue object is used for routing requests and managing how many can be sent at once. This can be used in many ways, I tend to use them for categorized request (Authentication, Main, Upload Queue)

once inside the block you build a local NSHTTPURLResponse using the returned response. This is needed if you want the status code returned. (doesn't exist in the standard NSURLResponse object)

responseData is the data that can usually be converted right to a string or run through a deserializer to obtain human readable data.

Pretty simple explanation, delegates get you in trouble if you have no idea how to manage multiple requests from the same object (probably why I prefer blocks) :-)

Like always delegates or blocks you want to trigger your UI to update after you receive the response, but not be held back waiting for the request to complete, if you were loading data into a table you would call the request on load and supply some form of progress hud telling them a request is being made, once the data is received you remove the hud and reload the table data. HUDs MUST be called on the main thread so you will definitely need to handle that, I usually just build extensions and use performSelectorOnMainThread, however a better way might be to wrap your function in dispatch_async and call you're hud show / hide code outside of that.

Comment: Thanks Holyprin,I am aware of AFNetworking and ASIHTTPRequest However I am not allowed to use the third party libraries, thats the reason am trying to start from the scratch. So it would be great if you provide me your tutorial.

Comment: Guess that makes sense, I'll write once up here in a few.

Comment: How do I notify my UI that a task has been completed say I am downloading some images, to update itself.

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread / performSelector and or [object setTarget:forControlEvents:] on UIControl type objects, and even using GCD, there are quite a few ways to notify the main thread to update the UI.

Comment: Is there a provision for cancelling the requests? From StackoverFlow discussions it looks like its not possible. And also is there a way for timeout?