# Sometimes login will take long time

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest

I am new in **iOS** application development. I have one problem in login page.
Sometimes it will take long time for log in. I am using this code to send or receive a request from a httpserver.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonData1
                                                   options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    jsonString= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"converted json string is %@",jsonString);
}

NSData *postData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"method=methodName&email=%@&password=%@", user_name, pass_word] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding ];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[postData length]];


jsonData=[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"the final passing json data is %@",jsonData);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:urladdress"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"\"Accept\""];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"\"Content-Type\""];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"\"Content-Length\""];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSError *requestError = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&requestError];

//if communication was successful

if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300) {
    NSError *serializeError = nil;

    NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithString :[urlData bytes]];

    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                              options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                              error:&serializeError];
    NSLog(@"recdata %@",jsonData);
}
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connection)
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is succesful");
    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
[connection start];

[self readFromDataBase];
if (dataCheck==true) {
    [self checkPassword];
}
```

is there any way to login faster.?

Comment: You are connecting to the same server twice.

Comment: I don't get the issue... the network has _not_ a constant speed, the response time depends on many components which are outside of your app. what kinda solution do you expect actually...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the connection is slow because your server or your connection quality.

Did you try with async? It won't freeze your app when waiting the respond

[Asynchronous NSURLConnection Scheme Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902102/asynchronous-nsurlconnection-scheme-tutorial)

For your program, replace the sendSync method:

```
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&requestError];
```

by sendAsync method:

```
    NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [mainQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];    

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:mainQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *urlData, NSError *requestError) {
        // doing somethings ...
        // if communication was successful ...
    }];
```

Comment: In my program where I have to write the asynchronous NSURLConnection?

Comment: thanks, it's working great. One problem is there after login if I not will not do anything then it will generate exception like pthread kill...

Comment: i am getting following error. Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Comment: For the time out, you can set: request.timeoutInterval = 10.0;